# How to get the GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR value?

Tags: opengl, c++

This code snippet:

```
GLint versionMajor;
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glGetIntegerv(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, &versionMajor);
std::cout << "Version major:" << version << std::endl;
```

prints "3" in my screen, but in the first line I set the the GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR to "2". How I can get back that value?

Comment: `glGetIntegerv(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` I'm pretty sure that doesn't work. OpenGL doesn't know what to do with `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the GLFW docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_ctx), the context version hint acts as a *minimum* version, i.e. the context you actually get may be a higher version than what you request. However, the context should be backward-compatible, so even if you get a GL 3.x context you're OK to use GL 2.x code.